# Port forwarding and IPv6

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, port-forwarding

I have a basic small server that I run on my own computer, which I can access
like this:

```
localhost:3000
```

However I would also like to access the server from outside my home, for example
using my phone browser. On another forum, someone said I could use one of these
options:

- With IPv6: yes, if you open the port in your firewall
- With IPv4 you can do it with a port forward

but I don't really know how to do either one. It seems like IPv6 would be the
better option, but I don't know if I am even using a firewall. In Windows settings,
I have firewall turned off. Can someone advise on how I can access this server
from another network?

Comment: You have to forward the traffic regardless if you are using IPv4 or IPv6 since your forwarding traffic from outside of your intranet into it. You should determine if your ISP has assigned you an IPv4 or IPv6 address and edit your question

Comment: Don't mix up regular "forwarding" and "port-forwarding" (the latter being a name for _address translation_). But yes, check whether your home connection has IPv6, and whether your _phone_ Internet connection has IPv6. Specify what router you're using at home. And for the love of, **stop turning off the firewall.**

Comment: Btw, if this server program listens to 127.0.0.1 and/or ::1 specifically, then you have more to adjust in addition to port forwarding and/or firewall configuration.

Answer (score 5):

There are four parts to making your network service accessible from the Internet:

1. Make sure the service is accessible over the network. This involves:

- Making sure it isn't bound to the loopback address (127.0.0.1 or ::1) which is only reachable on the computer itself. How this is done depends on the application providing the service and on the operating system of the computer.
- Making sure it isn't blocked by the host firewall, either (dangerous) by turning the host firewall off or (better) by explicitly allowing incoming connections to the service in the host firewall. How to do this depends on the operating system and the host firewall in use.

2. Provide a public IP address for the service. This is where the essential difference exists between IPv4 and IPv6:

- With IPv6, you make sure your computer itself has a public address. In most typical settings you don't have to do anything for that beyond enabling IPv6 on your router. Your router gets a public IPv6 prefix from your provider and assigns public IPv6 addresses from that block to the devices on your network without further ado.
- With IPv4, because of the global address shortage you'll typically get only a single public address from your provider which your router itself will occupy. Machines on the Internet can only connect to that public address. To work around that, you'll have to set up TCP port forwarding on your router to pass incoming connections arriving at your router and destined for your service on to your computer. The exact steps for doing this differ between router models of different manufacturers and sometimes even between different models of the same manufacturer.

3. Making that public address known to the client system from which you want to connect to the service. The direct approach would be to read the address from the computer itself (IPv6) or from your router (IPv4) and type it into your client. However most home Internet connections get only dynamic addresses which means the public address changes regularly, making this approach impractical. The way around that is to subscribe to a DynDNS service. That service provides a DNS name which is automatically updated to whatever IP address your service is currently reachable at. There are several DynDNS offers to choose from, both paid and free. Details of setting it up depend on which one you choose.
4. Allow incoming connections for the service in your router's firewall. For IPv4 most routers do this automatically when you set up the port forwarding (step 2). For IPv6 you'll have to configure it manually. Again, details vary wildly between router models.

Each of those steps can and should be tested individually before proceeding to the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am stuck as "Making sure it isn't bound to the loopback address". Mine is bound to that, and I dont know how to change it. So the rest of the answer wont help me, until I can resolve that

Comment: That's typically a configuration option in the service. As you didn't share any information about what that service is, I cannot help you there.

Comment: Its not a "service", its just a small server that I wrote

Comment: If you wrote it yourself then you can just modify it to bind to the wildcard address instead of the loopback address.

Comment: I dont know how to do that. This is my code https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Web_server#Go

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Go.

Comment: @Zombo : I’m coming late here… while not familiar with Go, I still can tell you that you have to make sure you’re server isn’t bound to the loopback address *only*. Now, if it is bound to the loopback address and nothing else, then you have a problem, in which case I advise you to modify the http.ListenAndServe function parameter and try "*:8080" instead. But frankly, I suspect it’s already bound to everything…